# Android-Kotlin: How to dynamically put the elements on the screen in specific order (not just vertically or horizontally)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, arraylist, view

This is gonna be a card game.
At the beginning there are 4 cards already on the screen (*blue squares* #1-4 [at the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4RHC.png)).
When user takes card from the deck (*brown square*) and in some cases needs to put it to his cards (to the *grey field*), all new cards have to be placed to the right and first card lays up (*yellow square* #5), then another new card goes down (*yellow* #6), then if needed one more card it should lay up again (*yellow* #7) and so on. We don't know in advance how many cards user will have to take - each game it can be different amount.

Which type of view should I use to be able to dynamically put the cards in such order like I described abowe?
And also how can I make users' cards be always automatically centred, so if the new cards (like #7) come up, all the cards are moving to the left?

Sorry for my bad drawing, I hope the picture should help to understand the logic. And thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Are you using traditional Android views or Compose?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I am new to Android, just learning still, so now I use traditional views but if there is something that can help me to solve my question, I am ready to learn new things

Comment: For better performance I'll recommend to use  Recyclerview, it will handle for you the item's alignments & (animations) in addition to drag and drop if needed.